# What's the bit pattern for minimal value in double 64 bit

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

I assumed that the minimal positive value that can be put into double floating point is this

```
0 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And in scientific form it's this:

```
1 x 2^{-1023}
```

However, [this article](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html#specials) states that:

> As mentioned above, zero is not directly representable in the straight
>   format, due to the assumption of a leading 1 (we'd need to specify a
>   true zero mantissa to yield a value of zero). Zero is a special value
>   denoted with an exponent field of all zero bits, and a fraction field
>   of all zero bits.

So what's the pattern for minival positive value?

Comment: Do you mean the minimum *positive* value?

Comment: Yes. Updated the question

Comment: I think that's correct, yes. The format is designed so that an *integer* 64-bit comparison will return correct answers for `>` and `<`, so any positive value will by that criteria be larger than the all-zeros value.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks. [this article](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html#specials) however states that the bit pattern of all zeros denote zero value.

Comment: OK well then that's the smallest non-negative value :)

Comment: @Pointy, indeed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the exponent part is all zero, the numbers are *subnormals* or *denormals*, where the implicit digit is 0 instead of 1. Therefore

```
0 00000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

is zero, and the next number

```
0 00000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

is the smallest positive number, being equal to

0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>-1022</sup> = 2<sup>-1074</sup> ≈ 5.0×10<sup>-324</sup>

UPDATE: so why is the exponent -1022, when the bias is 1023? The subnormals have the same exponent as the first [binade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade) of normal floats (so 1-1023 = 1022). This is so that the spread is continuous, i.e. the largest subnormal is

0.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>-1022</sup>

and the next floating point number (the smallest normal):

1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>-1022</sup>

Comment: thanks, how many digits do you have here `0.000000000000000000....`? I've counted 54, it seems to be too much. It's gotta to be 52 or 53 (if implicit 0 is added)

Comment: Woops, updated (I had copied yours from the question, which was off by 1 place)

Comment: thanks, so for subnormals instead of 1 the implicit zero is added?

Comment: thanks. One more question. Why is exponent `-1022`? With the bias `K=2^{10}-1=1023` the exponent of all zeros is `-1023`, not `-1022`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I still don't understand though how should I calculate the exponent subnormals - should I ask another question?

Comment: Perhaps that would be best.

Comment: [there you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956130/how-is-exponent-calculated-for-subnormals-in-floating-point) :)

Comment: Hey, did you get a chance to look at the question I linked? There is one answer there which says that the exponent is 1023, not 1022. I'm confused :(. Can you please take a look?