# How is exponent calculated for subnormals in floating point

Tags: binary, floating-point

Suppose I have the floating point bits representation like this:

```
0 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

I know that the floating point numbers with the exponent of all zeros are called subnormals or denormals. And the exponent is calculated differently than for normal floating point numbers where the bias is taken into account.

So how is exponent calcualted for subnormals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponent isn't calculated differently. The only difference subnormals have is a leading 0 instead of a leading 1 (so your example is equal to `0.0000···0001 * 2^-1022` instead of `1.0000···0001 * 2^-1022`.

If you're looking for an equivalent mantissa and exponent such that there *is* a leading 1, just count the leading zeros in the mantissa and add one, subtract the result from the original exponent, and also shift the mantissa left by the result (so `0.000000101 * 2^-50` would result in 6+1 and become `1.01 * 2^-57`).

Comment: thanks for your answer. The question comes from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39945671/2545680) where the exponent is suggested to be `-1022`.  So what's the exponent?

Comment: This is a bit misleading: for a positive normal number in an IEEE 754 binary format, you interpret the value as `1.<fraction_bits> * 2^<exponent_bits - bias>`. But for a positive subnormal or zero, you want instead `0.<fraction_bits> * 2^<exponent_bits - bias + 1>` (where of course the exponent_bits have value zero in this case). So in that sense, the exponent *is* calculated differently. (And for `binary64`, the minimum representable value is `0.0000...0001 * 2^(-1022)`, or `2^(-52) * 2^(-1022) = 2^(-1074)`.)

Comment: What he said. Forgot about the special rules for subnormals.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, can you please post your comment as an answer?